# Ideal way of sending multiple files to multiple FTP accounts using multiple threads via windows service?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services

Windows service needs to send multiple files to multiple FTP folders based on the client id .I have the basic operation working where the timer calls **PerformTimerOperation** every 5 minutes.

**Clients.xml**

```
<clients>
  <client>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>client 1</name>
    <ftp>FTP URL1</ftp>
    <username>FTP USer1</username>
    <password>FTP Pass1</password>
  </client>
  <client>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>client 2</name>
    <ftp>FTP URL2</ftp>
    <username>FTP USer2</username>
    <password>FTP Pass2</password>
  </client>
</clients>
```

**Clients.cs**

```
public class Clients
    {
        public string ClientName { get; set; }
        public string ClientId { get; set; }
        public string FTP { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public Clients()
        {
            ClientName = string.Empty;
            ClientId = string.Empty;
            FTP = string.Empty;
            Username = string.Empty;
            Password = string.Empty;
        }

        public List<Clients> GetClientList()
        {
            List<Clients> result;
            // load data file
            using (XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader("clients.xml"))
            {
                XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlReader);

                var Clients = from clientItem in xdoc.Root.Elements()
                              select new Clients
                              {
                                  ClientName = clientItem.Element("name").Value,
                                  ClientId = clientItem.Element("id").Value,
                                  FTP = clientItem.Element("ftp").Value,
                                  Username = clientItem.Element("username").Value,
                                  Password = clientItem.Element("password").Value
                              };

                result = Clients.ToList();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

**ServiceImplementation.cs**

```
    public void OnStart(string[] args)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                keepLooping = true;

                //new System.Threading.Thread(PerformTimerOperation).Name = "Thread ";
                new System.Threading.Thread(PerformTimerOperation).Start();
            }


    PerformTimerOperation
            private void PerformTimerOperation(object state)
            {
                while (keepLooping)
                {
                    Clients objClient= new Clients();
                    List<Clients> objClientList = objClient.GetClientList();

                    foreach (var list in objClientList)
                    {
                        ConsoleHarness.WriteToConsole(ConsoleColor.Cyan, list.ClientId);
                        ConsoleHarness.WriteToConsole(ConsoleColor.Cyan, list.ClientName);
                        ConsoleHarness.WriteToConsole(ConsoleColor.Cyan, list.FTP);
                        ConsoleHarness.WriteToConsole(ConsoleColor.Cyan, list.Username);
                        ConsoleHarness.WriteToConsole(ConsoleColor.Cyan, list.Password);

***// Here I would like to call individual client database, get data, convert to XLS and send to appropriate FTP.
// So, if I have 2 clients in the XML file. This loop will call each client one by one and send files to corresponding FTP.
// Is it possible to assign each operation to separate thread so that multiple threads can start sending files to different FTP accounts simultaneously?***

                     }

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50000);
                }

            }
```

Best practice and performance is really important. 
Also, open to constructive criticism with current approach.

Comment: How does it determine which files belong to / go to a particular client?

Comment: Based on list.ClientId. Client id is typically the database name. @Galactic

Comment: Ok, so it's getting the list of files from a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some notes and suggestions:

- **Use a [timer and event subscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) instead of thread sleep.**
- Extract the functionality for a client - get list of files, process, send - to a separate method.  Method will take the instance of `Clients` from the current loop iteration.
- Once it's a separate method, you can [spawn a new thread (from the ThreadPool)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yd16hza.aspx), passing this method name as the thread method and any relevant parameters.
- Make GetClientList() static so you don't have to instantiate an instance of the class to call it.  You'd call `Clients.GetClientList()` instead.

Note that, in the example on the MSDN site, they use a `Thread.Sleep()` to simulate thread synchronization.  In your case, this isn't necessary since you're running a service - the main thread isn't going to end until you tell it to do so.

---

Assuming you implement a method such as `SendFilesToClient(Clients currentClient)`, you would queue it something like this:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(SendFilesToClient), list);
```

Comment: You're sleeping your main (service) thread, which means that it can't properly respond to system events while it's sleeping.  This is a contrived example because the system would probably terminate it, but consider a case where it triggers, then goes to sleep for 5 minutes.  30 seconds later, you want to reboot the system.  The service isn't going to get the "Stop" command for another 4:30.

Comment: Thanks @Galactic got it. By any chance, could you please post a piece of code that implements ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem in relation to my code. I am new to this kind of project and I will appreciate if you could help me with the code.

Comment: Perfect @Galactic. Possible, last question: Can you tell me what's going to happen in terms of process (i.e. whether one queue is going to send files to multiple clients one by one or multiple threads will perform the task of sending files). I just want to be able to visualize the process of thread(s) sending files to FTP.

Comment: Doing it this way, each queue will operate completely independently - each thread will handle all of the work for a specific client, so if you've got *n* clients in your list, it would spawn *n* threads and process all of them concurrently.

Comment: Awesome explanation and thanks for all your time and help @Galactic. Honestly, I wasn't expecting anyone to go this far answering my question.

Comment: What difference does it makes if I use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(SendFilesToClient), list); inside the for loop vs using for lopp inside SendFilesToClient function? Which approach you think is better?

Comment: It would flip the relationship between clients and threads - all of your clients would run serially (one after the other) on one thread instead of in parallel.

Comment: Sorry, which approach would make it process serially?

Comment: If you put your loop inside SendFilesToClient.

Comment: Could you please provide some feedback on this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095662/how-to-use-threadpool-queueuserworkitem-and-lock-with-multi-threaded-service ?