# How to use Threadpool.QueueUserWorkItem in a windows service?

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, windows-services, queueuserworkitem

I have a windows service where I am using Threadpool.QueueUserWorkItem. The service connects to multiple client databases, grabs data, converts to XLS and send files to the corresponding FTP.

**I have 3 questions regarding the code below:**

1. Am I using the Threadpool.QueueUserWorkItem correctly?
2. Do I need to use Lock anywhere in the code to avoid issues? If yes, where and to what object.
3. Is there anything that is not correct in the code? If yes, what and how to deal with it?

**Code:**

```
private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(50000);

public void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            CLE.WriteToEventLog("Service Started");
            try
            {
                aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(PerformTimerOperation);
                aTimer.Enabled = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                CLE.WriteToEventLog("Error Starting Service: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

private void PerformTimerOperation(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            CLE.WriteToEventLog("Timer Operation Started");
                Clients objClient = new Clients();
                List<Clients> objClientList = Clients.GetClientList();

                foreach (var list in objClientList)
                {
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(SendFilesToClient), list);
                }                
        }

private void SendFilesToClient(Object stateInfo)
        {
            CLE.WriteToEventLog("Send Files To Client Started");
            Clients oClient = (Clients)stateInfo;
            CLE.WriteToEventLog("Start Proecessing Client: " + oClient.ClientName + ", ClientId: " + oClient.ClientId);

            connectionString = App.Database.PrimaryConnectionString(oClient.ClientId);

            string reports = oClient.Reports;
            string[] values = reports.Split(',').Select(sValue => sValue.Trim()).ToArray();

            foreach (string item in values)
            {
    //Send data to FTP based on cliend id
            }
            // At this point all reports are being sent to the FTP. We will update the database with LastExecutionDateTime + 1 hour. This will be used as DateFrom param for all reports for the next execution.
        }
```

The service works fine and I get appropriate results, but I need to make sure I am doing it right and don't run in to issues later.

Comment: Just did that @Gray. It's C# .NET 4.0

Comment: This looks fine to me.  Regarding your question #2, there shouldn't be any need for locking since your threads run completely independently.  Locks are necessary when you're coordinating access to a shared resource, but in this case each worker thread has its own database connection and is operating on a distinct set of "stuff".

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming your service is meant to keep running as opposed to being "one-and-done".  If so, please note that the [`AutoReset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset.aspx) property of the `System.Timers.Timer` class is set to `true` by default.  This simply means that the timer will continue to raise the `Elapsed` event each time the 50-second interval elapses (50000 milliseconds = 50 seconds).  If you know **for sure** that all of the  `SendFilesToClient` operations complete in plenty of time before the next interval elapses, then you should be ok.  However, I wouldn't bet on it.  What if the database is on the network and the network goes down?  What if the service is running on a slower system or one with fewer cores and all the work isn't completed in time?

You could potentially get around this by turning off the `AutoReset` feature like so.

```
private static var aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(50000) { AutoReset = false };
```

This means the `Elapsed` event will only fire once.  Inside the `PerformTimerOperation`, simply reset the `Enabled` property to `true` to restart the timer before exiting.

But this is an incomplete solution because the threads may still take too long to finish before the timer triggers another `Elapsed` event.  In this case, you might want to use a `ManualResetEvent` to signal when each thread is complete and suspend exiting `PerformTimerOperation` (and resetting the timer) until that occurs.  For example,

```
private void PerformTimerOperation(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    List<Clients> objClientList = new Clients().GetClientList();
    List<ManualResetEvent> handles = new List<ManualResetEvent();

    foreach (var list in objClientList)
    {
        // Create an MRE for each thread.
        var handle = ManualResetEvent(false);

        // Store it for use below.
        handles.Add(handle);

        // Notice two things:
        // 1.  Using new WaitCallback(...) syntax is not necessary.
        // 2.  Thread argument is now a Tuple object.
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(SendFilesToClient, Tuple.Create(list, handle));
    }

    // Wait for threads to finish.
    WaitHandle.WaitAll(handles.ToArray());

    // Reset the timer.
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
}
```

Now update `SendFilesToClient`.

```
private void SendFilesToClient(Object stateInfo)
{
    // The parameter is now a Tuple<T1, T2>, not a Clients object.
    var tuple = (Tuple<Clients, ManualResetEvent>)stateInfo;

    try
    {
        Clients oClient = tuple.Item1;

        // Do your work here...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle any exception here.
    }
    finally
    {
        // Signal that the work is done...even if an exception occurred.
        // Otherwise, PerformTimerOperation() will block forever.
        ManualResetEvent mreEvent = tuple.Item2;
        mreEvent.Set();
    }
}
```

In this fashion, the `PerformTimerOperation` will block on the [`WaitHandle.WaitAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6w25xa6.aspx) call until all the worker threads, e.g., `SendFilesToClient`, signal that they are finished.  At that point, you reset the timer and repeat on the next interval.

Sorry this is so long.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Not at all @Matt. This is wonderful explanation. Also, just FYI, this service needs to run every 1 hour in order to send files to the FTP. So I don't see any problem with service starting to run before finishing the previous task. Does that make any difference? Should I still go for your solution (implementing AutoReset and ManualReset) as a best practice? Any input on locking? Thanks!

Comment: Let's say that the previous task is still working, and a new task is started.  Are you opening database connections?  There might be a limit to how many simultaneous connections you can have open.  What about the recipient?  If they get files from the second task before the first task, is that a problem?  The likelihood of events such as these may be small, but a robust system deals with such issues.  You know your system better than me, so use your engineering judgment.  If the `PerformTimerOperation` normally takes no longer than a few minutes, I suspect you're ok.